# First analysis - Branch Plugin

Tags: sonarqube

We performed code analysis automatic with Jenkins + SonarQube.

We have the Enterprise license and I am adapting the projects to use the Branch Plugin, but I noticed that it is only possible to run with the parameter sonar.branch.name, if you have already run the main branch.

Is there no alternative to this?
For it would be necessary to work manually for this execution of the main branch, before running in an automated way.

Answer (score 1):

The project must exist before the first analysis. Whether it's created by the first analysis of the main branch or by [provisioning](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Project+Existence), it must exist before it can have branches.